# Are liquid car wax and car shampoo safe to use on motorcycle?

Tags: motorcycle, wax

I can't easily find wax and shampoo for motorcycle, but much easier to find these for car.

I don't know why but that's the truth. I searched "motorcycle wax" on Amazon India and all I could see results with car wax. There are a few motorcycle wax but they are not from brands I wanted to buy.

There are a few liquid wax in my budget but they have a car photo on it and mentions "car wax".

Same story for washing shampoo.

I have seen many Indian people on YouTube using them on their motorcycles.

So I'm not sure I should use it or not.

**Are liquid car wax and car shampoo safe to use on motorcycles?**

Comment: When you say ‘safe to use’, do you mean safe for the bike’s body work, or safe for the rider?  I would imagine you may not want to make any parts that you ‘grip’ with your legs too slippery with wax.

Comment: I mean safe for bike's body work (become as effective as it is for cars).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is Yes, they are safe to use.  Indeed the Autoglym Motorcycle Care pack includes the exact same polishes as they include in the Car Care pack.

Obviously with a motorcycle there are more exposed components so be careful not to get the electrical items too wet.

Interesting side note, I've also used car polish on my kitchen appliances with excellent results.

Answer (score 2):

Yes completely, I use either 3M or Motomax wax on my Duke 250 tank, headlamp housing, tank shrouds, and orange part of the frame. It takes a little effort but you will totally love the results. I also use it on my helmet!

Comment: Yeah I have used wax twice so far. No side effects indeed! But yeah it takes efforts.